# Handle errors at application or server level?

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7

When setting up asp.net error handlers for things like 404 errors, it is more 'efficient' to do this in IIS, or handle it in the Global.asax Application_Error event? I know the latter will be called, and I want to log this information in a database, but should I then just return without any redirect and let IIS do the redirect, or would it be better to do a response.redirect inside application_error once we've logged it?

Answer (score 0):

Handing in IIS is more efficient but in glabal.asax allows you to log it or react to it.

Remember the decision is not commonly yours but based on the mime setup. So if a resource has been set to be hanled as a static content, you will not receive it in the ASP.NET.